# Whether it is jointly convex or not?

Tags: matrices, functions, convex-analysis

I know that $f(x, Y)=x^HY^{-1}x$ is a convex function on $x$ and $Y$ jointly, where Y is positive definite.

Now, if $Y=\Sigma_{n=1}^{N}A_nSA_n^H+I$, where $S$ is positive semidefinite and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Can we say $f$ is jointly convex on $x$ and $Y$ ?